# Binary $[15,5,d]$ cyclic code

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

My goal is to find a generator polynomial for a binary $[15,5,d]$ cyclic code that corrects all errors with weight less than or equal to $3$.

I have to find a degree $10$ monic polynomial that divides $x^{15}-1$ ($\bmod 2$) and has weight $7$. If $15$ and $5$ were coprime I would know how to factor $x^{15}-1$ using cyclotomic theory. But that is not the case.

Is my reasoning ok? How do I factor $x^{15}-1\bmod 2$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try systematically dividing by quartics you will see that more polynomials than $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ factor into $x^{15}+1$ over $\mathbb F_2$:
$$x^{15}+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x+1)$$
Then
$$(x^2+x+1)(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^6+x^5+x^2+1$$
is the desired weight-$7$ polynomial.

Comment: Is this some kind of method, or is it a guess that quartics would divide $x^{15}-1$?

Comment: @XuguiManuel The standard approach for factoring polynomials over finite fields is to try irreducible polynomials in increasing degree. For the binary case, at low degrees the count of such polynomials is small enough to permit memorising them.

Comment: There are efficient algorithms for factoring polynomials over finite fields. But I agree that in a small case like this memorising irreducibles is more efficient. An irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ of degree $n$ is roughly the same as an $n$-bit prime number. So memorising irreducibles up to degree four, is at par with recalling the sequence of primes $2,3,5,7,11,13$. The latter does appear more frequently for the average math person :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I forgot to add "by hand" to my comment above. I actually used Singular, my favourite polynomial manipulation program, to find the answers for this question and [the one on the splitting field of $x^4+x+1$ in $\mathbb F_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4125202/357390) - it was then a matter of communicating it in a context where the computer might be barred. $\ddot\smile$