# Prove this $\mathbb F_2 (a)$ is splitting field of $X^4+X+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

I've been solving problems from my Galois Theory course, and I don't find the way to solve this one:

> Given the polynomial $f(X)=X^4+X+1\in\mathbb F_2[X]$, prove that
> $f(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_2[X]$. If $a$ is a root of $f(X)$,
> prove that $\mathbb F_2(a)$ is a splitting field of $f(X)$ over
> $\mathbb F_2$.

The work I've done so far:

Firstly, to prove $f(X)=X^4+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_2[X]$, I calculated all degree 4 non-irreducible polynomials (I did it by calculating all products possible of the degree 2 polyniomials, and $f(X)$ was not one of them. I just need to check this because, since $f(X)$ does not have roots in $\mathbb{F_2}$, the only way it can be reduced is by being product of two polynomials of degree 2).

After proving $f(X)$ is irreducible, I assumed $a$ is one of its roots, and here is where I don't know how to continue. I know that in order for it to be splitting field, it must have all roots of $f(X)$, so I must prove that, being $\beta, \gamma, \delta$ the other roots of $f(X)$, they verify that ther are inside $\mathbb F_2(a)$.

I tried Ruffini and got that
$$f(X)= (X-a)(X^3+aX^2+a^2X+1+a^3)$$
but I don't know how to continue. I considered using Vieta's formulas, but I'm not sure if that will help and how to properly use them in this case.

Is what I have already done correct? How can I end this problem? Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is better to write $\mathbf{F}_2$ rather than $\mathbf{Z}_2$ as the latter can be confused with the 2-adic integers.

Comment: @rae306 I see. Should I change it? I always use the $\mathbb Z_p$ notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach to show irreducibility is correct. Let me give a hint for the second part of the question.

You are working over the finite field $\mathbf{F}_2$, so you have Frobenius ($x\mapsto x^2$) at your disposal. Let $\alpha\in \overline{\mathbf{F}}_2$ be a root of $f=X^4+X+1\in \mathbf{F}_2[X]$. What is the orbit of $\alpha$ under Frobenius ? How can this be used to calculate the other roots of $f$ (and even prove irreducibility of $f$) ?

Comment: Oh, I dind't thought about using Frobenius. Thank you very much! I'll try it.

Comment: Great! The roots as given in the answer by Parcly Taxel are simply the elements of the Frobenius orbit of $\alpha$, they do not appear out out thin air :)

Answer (score 2):

We can easily verify that $a+1$, $a^2$ and $a^2+1$ are roots of the cubic, being the next things that should be tried because we are given that it is a splitting field (this is an extension of $\mathbb F_2$, so the constants are finite in number):
$$x^4+x+1=(x+a)(x+a^2)(x+a+1)(x+a^2+1)$$

Comment: My problem here is: how do I know that $a+1$, $a^2$ and $a^2+1$ are the roots? just trying? Or is there any way to reason it? Thanks for your answer

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso Just trying! This is a quartic, you can do this by hand!

Comment: No need for trial and error. Just apply the Frobenius automorphism $F$: $F(a)=a^2$, $F(a^2)=a^4=a+1$, $F(a+1)=a^2+1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am only going to take MA4203 Galois Theory next semester.

Comment: Ok. Hope you enjoy it!